# Logical operations on decimal numbers

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra

Is there any logical operations used on decimal numbers? Is there any operations like

5 and 6

4 or 1

3 exor 9

I believe arithmetic operations like addition and multiplication is not equivalent to logical operations like 'or' and 'and' respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those operations do not have a standard definition, so they can mean whatever you want them to mean. Some computer languages would interpret $0$ as `FALSE`and all other numbers as `TRUE`, but that's far from an established convention